# Configure WCF over SSL

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I'm using the following code successfully with HTTP but I would like to use SSL. When I change the endpoint address to https and modify the security mode to Transport in the web.config I get the error : "The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'."

This is a VB.net test form.

```
Imports WindowsApplication1.WCFService
Imports System.ServiceModel

Public Class Form1
Private WCFConnection As Service1Client 'Class reference from the ServiceReference

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If WCFConnection Is Nothing Then

        WCFConnection = New Service1Client(New System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding(), New EndpointAddress("https://www.mysite.com/Service1.svc?wsdl"))
    End If

    Dim NParray As String = WCFConnection.GetNP("8")
    TextBox1.Text = NParray



End Sub
End Class
```

Then here is the web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>

          <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>

        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://www.mysite.com/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="WCFService.IService1"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>

<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Is this the web.config you are using when you get the error?  The endpoint address should be https, not http. If this is not the configuration for the https, provide that instead of the one that works.

Comment: This is the working one. I've changed the Endpoint address to https, and Security Mode to Transport in the web.config. Then in the form i changed to https and get the error.

Comment: Do you get the error in the client or the service?

Comment: I get the error on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured this out.

Here is the web.config that I'm using

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<system.serviceModel>

  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ServBehave">
        <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="ServBehave" name="FILE_WCF.Srv">
      <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="custBind"
        contract="FILE_WCF.ISrv" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>

    <customBinding>
      <binding name="custBind">
        <binaryMessageEncoding></binaryMessageEncoding>
        <httpsTransport></httpsTransport>
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
  </bindings>

  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>

<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Here is the SVC file

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="VB" Debug="true" Service="FILE_WCF.Srv" CodeBehind="FILE.svc.vb" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
security mode="None"
```

use

```
security mode="None"
```